# How to handle refund problem when promotion applies in Order Level?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

We have a promotion with which you can buy some products as a bundle and it is a product promotion. Let me get visualize it. Assume that there are 2 containers which have some products like that:

**Container 1: P1,P2,P3,P4**

**Container 2: P5,P6,P7,P8**

When you choose one product from Container 1 and one another from Container 2, you will have a discount. Assume discount amount be $100. This discount is directly added to order(cart) not to order entry by Hybris.

**After adding this promotion to the cart, you can also add other products to it. Assume our new added product be P9.**

This scenario causes refund problem because of price distributions. I mean, Total discount amount ($100) is not related to P9 which was the last added product.

I need to know which products has resulted in the discount on the cart(order).

How to handle the refund of this kind of promotions?

Edit: Hybris v6.4 and rule based promotion engine

Answer (score 1):

I prefer override cart calculate strategy and calculate refund price and save it on order/cart item custom field before order completion. Also dispatch order level discounts to items. You can determine P9 while in calculation strategy. It is hard (may be impossible) to find promotions and calculations in refund step.

Comment: You are right but my scenario is already to distribute price before placing order. I just want to distribute it properly in cart calculation service but we could not see which products that are included in applied promotion although it is product promotion. The reason why is that hybris applies it on order level. In my example, The cart might has irrelevant products with the applied promotion. I found some workarounds. I can reach promotion containers products and check order entries with them. But it seems not to proper solution and it is a little bit cumbersome.